# How do I code a lognormal function?

Tags: probability

I have coded the algorithm for the pdf of the lognormal distribution - shown here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution and about a thousand other places I have looked at - but it does not give me the same results as using the lognormdist function in Calc (or the equivalent in Excel) for the same input parameters.

I have tried transforms of sigma and mu into m and v (and the other way round) to no avail.

For example, when I call lognormdist(12,10,5,0) I get 0.002148865

When I put the same parameters into a function I have coded (or crafted from basic functions in calc) I get 0.0013537142.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you setting the cumulative parameter to TRUE if you want to compute the pdf?  By the way, the d in pdf stands for "density", not "distribution", so my expectation is that most utility functions called "-DIST" are computing a cdf, not a pdf.

Comment: Hi Erick, and thanks for the quick response.
You were right - I was using 0 (=FALSE) but mistakenly typed it as TRUE, thinking it would make it easier to read. Sigh. (See? No good deed ever goes unpunished)
Regarding density vs distribution, I meant the pdf of the lognormal distribution. I have edited the question to clarify both of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a hunch that turned out to bear fruit.  You are taking the log base $10$ in the exponent of the term $e^{-(\ln x - \mu)^2/2\sigma^2}$.  It should be a natural log, but when I substitute a decimal log (which many less technical languages denote as just "LOG"), I get exactly $0.001353714152369$ which matches your undesired value to the full precision you specified.

Comment: Absolutely spot-on Erick. Thank you so much.
I knew that I should be using natural logs, but Calc provides functions log, log2 and log10. Log2 and Log10 are obvious. I assumed therefore that Log provided natural logs. In fact it takes a second parameter which allows you to use any base BUT it defaults to ... 10!

Anyway, further checking showed me that Calc also provides a specific natural log function - ln. Once I substituted this all was fine.